# PHP date/time help/

Tags: php

I keep getting a value of 0 for `$years` and `$months` when there should be a value other then 0 can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my code? And what I need to fix?

I'm trying to subtract two dates.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$delete_date = "2000-01-12 08:02:39";
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //current date

$diff = abs(strtotime($current_date) - strtotime($delete_date));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));

echo $current_date . '<br />';
echo $delete_date. '<br />';
echo $diff. '<br />';
echo $years. '<br />';
echo $months. '<br />';
```

Comment: I am getting value 11 for $years

Comment: I get 11 years and zero months when I run this code.

Comment: @Alex Howansky how can I get the total amount of months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try simply using the PHP function

DateTime::diff()

also known as

date_diff()

This will give you the difference in time which you can more easily parse into months and years.

Read this for more information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: aint this for PHP 5.3 which I dont have.

Comment: Do you get some meaningful value for $diff? I just ran the code as it is and got the correct answer. (Note that currently the amount of months _is_ zero.)

Comment: how can I get the total amount of months?

Answer (score 0):

Note, you don't need to do this:

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$diff = abs(strtotime($current_date) - strtotime($delete_date));
```

You can just do this:

```
$diff = abs(time() - strtotime($delete_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

$month is zero since the result of

($diff - $years * (60*60*24*365))/(60*60*24) = 5.4510763888889

That means only 5 days. Then when you try to make these 5 days in terms of month gives you the result as 0.18176195987654

Floor(0.18176195987654) will definitely give you 0 month. no doubt in it.

Then i am getting $year as 11 as others told.